# Как в rabbitmq накопить определённое кол-во строк и запустить эту пачку в callback?

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq, clickhouse

На данный момент работает так - идёт запрос с множеством данных на сервис А, с него данные посылаются в очередь в `rabbitmq`, откуда читаются по одному сообщению сервисом В и пишутся в `CLickHouse`. Нужно сделать так, чтобы в сервисе В сообщения накапливались до заданного размера (формировалась пачка) и разом записывались в `ClickHouse`.
Используется `php/Laravel`.

```
public function listen(ClickHouseServer $houseServer, string $queue)
{
    $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(
        env('AMQP_SERVER'),
        env('AMQP_HOST'),
        env('AMQP_USER'),
        env('AMQP_PASSWORD')
    );

    $channel = $connection->channel();

    $channel->queue_declare(
        $queue,    #queue name - Имя очереди может содержать до 255 байт UTF-8 символов
        false,        #passive - может использоваться для проверки того, инициирован ли обмен, без того, чтобы изменять состояние сервера
        true,        #durable - убедимся, что RabbitMQ никогда не потеряет очередь при падении - очередь переживёт перезагрузку брокера
        false,        #exclusive - используется только одним соединением, и очередь будет удалена при закрытии соединения
        false        #autodelete - очередь удаляется, когда отписывается последний подписчик

    );

    /**
     * не отправляем новое сообщение на обработчик, пока он
     * не обработал и не подтвердил предыдущее. Вместо этого
     * направляем сообщение на любой свободный обработчик
     */
    $channel->basic_qos(
        null,   #размер предварительной выборки - размер окна предварительнйо выборки в октетах, null означает “без определённого ограничения”
        config('app.BASIC_QOS'),    #количество предварительных выборок - окна предварительных выборок в рамках целого сообщения
        null    #глобальный - global=null означает, что настройки QoS должны применяться для получателей, global=true означает, что настройки QoS должны применяться к каналу
    );

    /**
     * оповещает о своей заинтересованности в получении
     * сообщений из определённой очереди. В таком случае мы
     * говорим, что они регистрируют получателя, или устанавливают
     * подписку на очередь. Каждый получатель (подписка) имеет
     * идентификатор, называемый “тег получателя”.
     */
    $channel->basic_consume(
        $queue,        #очередь
        '',                  #тег получателя - Идентификатор получателя, валидный в пределах текущего канала. Просто строка
        false,               #не локальный - TRUE: сервер не будет отправлять сообщения соединениям, которые сам опубликовал
        false,               #без подтверждения - false: подтверждения включены, true - подтверждения отключены. отправлять соответствующее подтверждение обработчику, как только задача будет выполнена
        false,                 #эксклюзивная - к очереди можно получить доступ только в рамках текущего соединения
        false,                 #не ждать - TRUE: сервер не будет отвечать методу. Клиент не должен ждать ответа
        array($houseServer, 'push')    #функция обратного вызова - метод, который будет принимать сообщение
    );

    while (count($channel->callbacks)) {
        $channel->wait();
    }

    $channel->close();
    $connection->close();
}
```

`$channel->basic_qos` - не помогло. Какие есть варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого необходимо читать сообщения из очереди и записывать их в массив пока не накопится пачка нужного размера на стороне сервиса В.

Но я бы предложил Вам полностью отказаться от сервиса B и выполнять чтение очереди непосредственно в ClickHouse. Благо там все для этого есть. А именно - движок [RabbitMQ](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/ru/engines/table-engines/integrations/rabbitmq/)

Пример создания таблицы для чтения очереди. Параметры описан по ссылке выше. `rabbitmq_max_block_size` и `rabbitmq_flush_interval_ms` - то что Вам нужно для регулирования размера блоков для записи.

```
  CREATE TABLE queue (
    key UInt64,
    value UInt64,
    date DateTime
  ) ENGINE = RabbitMQ SETTINGS rabbitmq_host_port = 'localhost:5672',
                            rabbitmq_exchange_name = 'exchange1',
                            rabbitmq_format = 'JSONEachRow',
                            rabbitmq_num_consumers = 5,
                            date_time_input_format = 'best_effort';
```

Просто чтение из данно таблицы не эффективно, так как каждое сообщение можно прочитать 1 раз, это скорее полезно для отладки. Для записи данных из очереди в таблицу используйте материализованное представление.

Для начала необходимо задать саму целевую таблицу.

```
  CREATE TABLE daily (key UInt64, value UInt64)
    ENGINE = MergeTree();
```

После этого создаете материализованное представление которое будет читать таблицу очереди и инсертить данные в целевую.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW consumer TO daily
    AS SELECT key, value FROM queue;

  SELECT key, value FROM daily ORDER BY key;
```